# VBA how to loop trough selected cells

Tags: html, excel, vba

The following script is suppose to take values from excel file to populate a html web page form:

```
Sub Autofill()

    Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    Dim IE As Object
    
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    Set rng = Range("A12:A21")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV/Lists/IPV%20Appeals%20tracker/Issue/newifs.aspx?Source=https%3A%2F%2Fshare%2Eamazon%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FIPV%2FLists%2FIPV%2520Appeals%2520tracker%2FAll%2520items%2Easpx&RootFolder="
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    
    Loop
    
    
    
    For Each Row In rng
    
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T9").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Cells(Row, 41).Value
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T8").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Cells(Row, 39).Value

    Next Row





    
    
End Sub
```

This is what i wrote, i know the script works but the issue is the range im creating, as I am referencing `Set rng = Range("A12:A21")` because i want to reference from row 12 to row 21, that i then want to use for the for loop, but i seem to be making a mistake.

Thanks for taking your time to see this.

ORIGINAL FUNCTIONING SCRIPT:
This is to edit only one row, without the forloop.

```
Sub Autofill()


    Dim IE As Object
    
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV/Lists/IPV%20Appeals%20tracker/Issue/newifs.aspx?Source=https%3A%2F%2Fshare%2Eamazon%2Ecom%2Fsites%2FIPV%2FLists%2FIPV%2520Appeals%2520tracker%2FAll%2520items%2Easpx&RootFolder="
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T9").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AO12") 'ass tag
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T8").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AM12") 'man tag
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T1").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AC12") 'Task ID
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T2").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("F12") 'mcid
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T5").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("C12") 'country
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T19").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AH12") 'type of audit
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T3").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AL12") 'site
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T4").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AN12") 'Marketplace
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T6").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AD12") 'time
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T10").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("K12") 'ass act
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T11").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("L12") 'corr act
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T12").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("U12") 'siv act
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T13").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("V12") ' cor siv act
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_T43").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("Q12") 'metric name
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_D14").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("X12") 'siv rfd reaspm
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_D15").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AI12") 'data correctly capt
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_D15").Value = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("AA12") 'if correctly cap
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_D62").Value = "No"
    IE.document.getElementByID("ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_RTC60_RTI1_RT1_newRichText").innerHTML = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Range("P12") 'annot
End Sub
```

Comment: `Row` in your script is a range use `Row.row`

Comment: I did ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits").Cells(Row.Row, 41).Value but still get object required.

Comment: That is probably a failure to get the elementid

Comment: The get element ID works as I have a functioning script that populates those ElementID. I have pasted the functioning script.

Comment: You are setting form control `_V1_I1_D15` twice , is that correct ?

Comment: Yes sorry I removed it and still works, it just does it twice. But anyways the second patch of code is functional. The first one is where I try to loop trough the rows and doesn't work. I think the rnge that I'm looping is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a dictionary as a mapping between the ID's and the columns.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Autofill()

    Dim dict As Object, key
    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dict.Add "T9", "AO"  'ass tag
    dict.Add "T8", "AM" 'man tag
    dict.Add "T1", "AC" 'Task ID
    dict.Add "T2", "F" 'mcid
    dict.Add "T5", "C" 'country
    dict.Add "T19", "AH" 'type of audit
    dict.Add "T3", "AL" 'site
    dict.Add "T4", "AN" 'Marketplace
    dict.Add "T6", "AD" 'time
    dict.Add "T10", "K" 'ass act
    dict.Add "T11", "L" 'corr act
    dict.Add "T12", "U" 'siv act
    dict.Add "T13", "V" ' cor siv act
    dict.Add "T43", "Q" 'metric name
    dict.Add "D14", "X" 'siv rfd reaspm
    'dict.Add "D15", "AI" 'data correctly capt
    dict.Add "D15", "AA" 'if correctly cap
    
    Const URL = "https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV/Lists/IPV Appeals tracker/Issue/newifs.aspx" & _
                 "?Source=https://share.amazon.com/sites/IPV/Lists/" & _
                 "IPV%20Appeals%20tracker/All%20items.aspx&RootFolder="
    
    Const PREFIX = "ctl00_ctl33_g_62154394_4b95_41ba_ab7f_81e2f3297aa2_FormControl0_V1_I1_"
    
    Dim IE As Object
    Set IE = GetObject("new:{D5E8041D-920F-45e9-B8FB-B1DEB82C6E5E}")
    
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate URL
    
    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop
    
    Dim r As Long, ID As String
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Audits")
        For r = 12 To 21
        
            For Each key In dict.keys
                IE.document.getElementByID(PREFIX & CStr(key)).Value = .Range(dict(key) & r)
                'Debug.Print key, dict(key) & r
            Next
            IE.document.getElementByID(PREFIX & "D62").Value = "No"
            IE.document.getElementByID(PREFIX & "RTC60_RTI1_RT1_newRichText").innerHTML = .Range("P" & r) 'annot
            
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```